# wordpress woocommerce minimal image size

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with scale in my product images. When I choose an image whose width > 400px and height > 250px, cropping the image works fine. However, when the image has width < 400px and height < 250px it's not working.

It is possible to block the upload when an image is too small? Because when the image is too small the script cannot crop the image and the thumbnail is too small.

Comment: No, you can't block uploads like this, because PHP **MUST** have a copy of the file to read from to figure out the dimensions. You can only REJECT it, afterwards, if it doesn't mean your requirements.

Comment: How I can do this ?

Comment: you write code...

Comment: I know that already :) I wrote a few simple plugins for WP but how can I edit woocommerce make it work?